# When does a process handle a signal

Tags: linux, signals

I want to know when does a linux process handles the signal. 
Assuming that the process has installed the signal handler for a signal, I wanted to know when would the process's normal execution flow be interrupted and signal handler called.

According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html, the process would handle the signal when it exits from a system call. This would mean that a normal instruction like a = b+c (or its equivalent machine code) would not be interrupted because of signal.

Also, there are system calls which would get interrupted (and fail with EINTR or get restarted) upon receiving a signal. This means that signal is processed even before the system call completes. This behaviour seems to b conflicting with what I have mentioned in the previous paragraph.

So, I am not clear as to when is the signal processed and in which process states would it be handled by the process. Can it be interrupted

1. Anytime it enters from kernel space to user space, or
2. Anytime it is in user space, or
3. Anytime the process is scheduled for execution by the scheduler

Thanks!

Comment: Handling a signal != receiving a signal.

Comment: I understand that Handling a signal != receiving a signal. Assuming that the signal handler has been installed, I wanted to know when is that signal handler called. (I updated the text of my question to avoid some confusion as pointed by you.)

Comment: It depends on the signal, as well. Some (SIGILL, SIGSEGV, SIGKILL, SIGBUS, etc.) are delivered and processed immediately, others, as you note, are only checked on system call and other user-kernel boundaries (scheduler, etc.). Perhaps narrowing down what your actual question is would help a bit...

Comment: @twalberg I did not have any specific signal in mind, but wanted to know the general rules regrading handling the signals. So, as you have mentioned, different signals are processed differently as opposed to a single scheme of handling signals. Could you specify the different categories of signals for which the signal handling is differently. Thanks!!!

Comment: That's a fairly big topic, so rather than trying to describe it here, I would recommend reading (at least) the man page `signal(7)` (on Linux, assuming you have them installed, just type `man 7 signal`). If you don't have man pages installed, they should be pretty easy to find online as well...

Comment: @twalberg thanks fir the response. That really helped. I found the following text in the man page "Signals may be delivered any time a process enters the operating system (e.g., during a system call, page fault or trap, or clock interrupt)." This is quite the opposite of what is stated on tldp.org, i.e. signals are delivered when the process exits from operating system. Also, it mentions what system calls will always fils with EINTR because of signal, but I couldn't find much information on time of delivery of the signal.

Comment: @twalberg could you please add your comment as answer to that we can vote it as well. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

> According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html, the process would handle the signal when it exits from a system call. This would mean that a normal instruction like a = b+c (or its equivalent machine code) would not be interrupted because of signal.

Well, if that were the case, a CPU-intensive process would not obey the process scheduler. The scheduler, in fact, can interrupt a process at any point of time when its time quantum has elapsed. Unless it is a FIFO real-time process.

A more correct definition: One point when a signal is delivered to the process is when the control flow leaves the kernel mode to resume executing user-mode code. That doesn't necessarily involve a system call.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the semantics of signal handling are documented (for Linux, anyway - other OSes probably have similar, but not necessarily in the same spot) in the section 7 `signal` manual page, which, if installed on your system, can be accessed like this:

```
man 7 signal
```

If manual pages are not installed, online copies are pretty easy to find.