# Can a program run while there are two signals pending

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a case with two signals SIG1 and SIG2 with handler1 and handler2 respectively. handler1 sends SIG2, with "kill(getpid(),SIG2)" assuming getpid returns the pid of the process, to the process.

Is it possible that the program runs for a while before handler2 runs?

```
int counter;
void sigalrm_handler (int num) {
   counter += 1;
}
int main (void) {
signal(SIGALRM, &sigalrm_handler);
counter = 2;
alarm(1);
sleep(1);
counter -= 3;
exit(counter);
return
}
```

Comment: Only as long as interrupts are disabled. Interrupts may be disabled during the (supposedly short) period of time in which you are handling the interrupt. This typically includes the execution of a relatively short piece of code within the IV (interrupt-vector), **and** the execution of the corresponding ISR (what you call "handler"), invoked at the end of the IV code. If the ISR takes a long time to execute then the scenario that you're describing might take place.

Comment: @barakmanos The case I am describing does not have any interrupts disabled anywhere, and by disabled you mean SIG_IGN (signal ignore) or masking of signal (sigprocmask)?

Comment: My comment is probably more suitable for a system with a single process (with several ISRs and possibly with several threads).

Comment: @barakmanos, what CodeWithPride calls a "handler" is what the docs [also](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html) [call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) a [handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Signals delivered to one process are not processed immediately(Maybe real-time signal do it that way, i am not sure for that).

Linux kernel(linux kernel 1.0 for sure) will process pending signals on return of system calls or on context switch(Kernel process scheduling). It may not changed that much on following version.

You can check [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320748/when-does-a-process-handle-a-signal) for reference, it's quite incomplete although.

Comment: in the following code:
    'int counter;
    void sigalrm_handler (int num) {
    counter += 1;
}
int main (void) {
signal(SIGALRM, &sigalrm_handler);
counter = 2;
alarm(1);
sleep(1);
counter -= 3;
exit(counter);
return 0;
}'

by your explanation, is it always necessary that handler for alarm will run after returning from sleep system call?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code in previous comment.

Comment: `signal` can be interrupted by signal that is not ignored and return number seconds left to sleep, in your case SIGALRM. Also note: from  man page of `signal` : `sleep()` may be implemented using SIGALRM, mixing calls to alarm() and sleep() is a bad idea